# HTML form tags in code blocks are actually rendered in Opera Mobile

Tags: bug, code-formatting, design

When viewing [PHP - Submit button does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486671/php-submit-button-does-nothing) in Opera Mobile 12.00, the

```
<form method='post' action='http://cogameservers.com/home/contact'>
Email: <input name='email' type='text' /><br />
Subject: <input name='subject' type='text' /><br />
Message:<br />
<textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
</textarea><br />
<input type='submit' />
</form>
```

section of the code not only renders the input areas, but also a working submit button. Strangely, I haven't found another question with the same effect.

Edit not by OP:

Here's what the page looks like in Opera 12 Mobile on ICS when using the desktop layout, the mobile interface and the mobile interface with Turbo disabled, respectively:

[image: form and button rendered on full site]

[image: form and button rendered on mobile site]

[image: display is correct with Turbo disabled]

Comment: Lol, then it's more likely a browser bug rather than SO bug, I guess.

Comment: Oh wow, repro'd on Opera Mobile 12.00 on an Honeycomb 3.2 tablet. This is a pretty serious bug in Opera

Comment: Reproed on Opera Mobile 12 on an ICS phone. The fault is with Opera Turbo; when I disabled that feature, the problem went away. I grabbed some screenshots, which I could add after I'm done with work, not that they'll do anyone here any good.

Comment: I filed a bug with Opera and linked them to this page. I used the e-mail address mso147570@mailinator.com. There is no public tracker page, but I got the message "If you would like to update your report with more information, please send an email to: ANDMEX-12912 [commercial at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign) bugs.opera.com."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a browser bug that we here cannot do a *single* thing about. Everything Stack Exchange can do has been done. Those opening and closing angled brackets are already escaped/encoded into HTML entities. If the browser is actually rendering the HTML, that's the browser's problem.

```
<pre><code>&lt;?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))

 {

$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
mail("necro@gophobia.com", $subject,
$message, "From:" . $email);
echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
}
else
 {
 echo "&lt;form method='post' action='http://cogameservers.com/home/contact'&gt;
Email: &lt;input name='email' type='text' /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
Subject: &lt;input name='subject' type='text' /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
Message:&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'&gt;
&lt;/textarea&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;input type='submit' /&gt;
&lt;/form&gt;";
}
?&gt;
</code></pre>
```