# Malicious payload in SO question

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, malicious-code

This question:

[Can Someone Tell Me Why This Is malicious..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313287/can-someone-tell-me-why-this-is-malicious)

someone has pasted code that (at a minimum) makes my ESET AV shut down my connection.  Can someone with an appropriate sandbox edit that out?

Comment: Do you mean... you actually *ran* that payload?

Comment: No, just browsing to the page set off ESET.

Comment: Some antivirus software is particularly stupid when it comes to stuff like that; it doesn't realize that the code won't actually be executed, it just sees it coming in over the network and panics

Comment: The angle brackets of the `<script>` tags are escaped, and the content resides in `<pre><code>`. Quite a paranoid tool indeed.

Comment: Stupid NOD32. :(

Comment: @MichaelMrozek it's just trying to be there for you, man. What if you [were running Opera](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147570/html-form-tags-in-code-blocks-are-actually-rendered-in-opera-mobile)?

Comment: @Pop, ah, sorry for my now defunct comment, those were indeed escaped `<form>` tags. Let's hope they at least handled escaped `<script>` tags in their unit tests.