# Review history appears not to escape HTML tags in titles of now-deleted questions for users without the privilege to view most deleted questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, xss

I found this bug when looking at [my review history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history). I found that the page shows the title of one of my reviews as:

```
How do I stretch the middle
height in a three-
layout?
```

In three lines, rather than the correct title of:

```
How do I stretch the middle <div> height in a three-<div> layout?
```

It seems here that the history isn't escaping the markup of the HTML tags. Can you fix this?

This is the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/984780) involved (the formatting error occurs in the review queue history page that links to that review).

---

As requested, here is a screenshot.

[image]

---

I'm using Firefox 17.0.1. The behavior happens even if I disable all add-ons.

Comment: Do you have a link to the specific page where this happens? I checked the history on the queues and on your profile and couldn't reproduce, so I imagine I was looking at the wrong pages.

Comment: Added more information.  This involves the review queue history.

Comment: It looks [right](http://so.mrozekma.com/review-history-html-escaping.png) in the 10k list (currently on page [679](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history?page=679)); possibly it only happens when you see your individual history

Comment: I see other titles with HTML tags in them on the [queue history you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history), [including the example you gave](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WDVDg.png). Do you have a screenshot of the page you were looking at, by any chance?

Comment: Yes it does, when I see my individual history.

Comment: [Here's the relevant page](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history?page=683) (for now at least). Looks normal to me.

Comment: I have seen the same problem: The question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077955/detect-if-input-type-file-is-supported renders the following review history (http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history): http://imgur.com/loxsx.

Comment: @Peter are you using a plugin/userscript to render [id:1234] after each question link?

Comment: I see this same behavior. Page is /review/low-quality-posts/history and the question being displayed is 12874538. The HTML (option, select) in the title is showing up as a working dropdown in FireFox 20.0.1.

Comment: Also view source shows unencoded raw HTML of the question title.

Comment: I also can see this in the first page of my [Low Quality Posts](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history?page=1). 10k users may still be able to tell me the actual title of [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/745469) but whatever it actually was something then _fixes_ the xhtml and displays the rest of the page with no tabulation at all!

Comment: Yeah, it is fixed for me now. And FYI the actual title was `HTML 2 PDF starts a new line for every </table>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was my bad - there was a bug here and it was of very limited exposure.  We have tested it a few times and believe to have found a fix.  As the title mentions you must have dealt with a post in review that contained tags in titles of now-deleted questions for users without the privilege to view most deleted questions.

Comment: Hmm, which reminds me...wonder if Opera Mobile fixed [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147570/html-form-tags-in-code-blocks-are-actually-rendered-in-opera-mobile)...

Comment: No, it happens even if I disable all add-ons.  I'm using Firefox 17.0.1, by the way.

Comment: I see the same behavior as the OP. Page is /review/low-quality-posts/history and the question being displayed is 12874538. The HTML (option, select) in the title is showing up as a working dropdown in FireFox 20.0.1. View source shows unencoded raw HTML of the question title.

Comment: @bmb Seems to be ok here http://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Swj.png

Comment: It is not bold on my screen. What does bold indicate vs. not bold? That the answer has been deleted and it's not clickable any longer? It may be clickable for you as a mod and the problem is only a problem when it's not surrounded by <a> tags?

Comment: Reproduced with [this test question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191995/test-question-please-ignore). Here's [a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NDVr9.png), and the page source includes: `<a href="/review/suggested-edits/16726">suggested edit</a> on <test question, please ignore>`.

Answer (score 7):

In comparing the behavior I see to the screenshots provided by the OP and by Geoff Dalgas, I suggest that the problem only occurs when the title displays on that page and is *not* clickable.

When the question is deleted, the title is no longer a link unless you have enough reputation or are a moderator. When the title is displayed as a link, apparently the html tags are encoded.

Since everyone who posted that it works for them has a high reputation or is a moderator, they are seeing the properly encoded text.

Those of us with with less reputation see only the text instead of a link, and I think that is where the encoding is being missed.

Comment: That may explain things; I've edited the title accordingly.