# Formatting on review history page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, internet-explorer-9, review-history

Illustration of the issue (notice the code-blocked "block" below the title):

[image]

Whereas it should look like this:

[image]

I'm able to reproduce it consistently (in IE9) on my reopen review history.

Possibly related to [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158906/167443)?

Comment: could you provide a link, or maybe describe more precisely what you're expecting to see/not see that isn't/is there?

Comment: @BenCollins It's this page: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/history

Comment: @Jim are you in compatibility mode by chance?

Comment: @NickCraver No. Switching to it causes the block to appear bigger (two lines of text, second blank). Shows up both with and without compatibility mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Review history appears not to escape HTML tags in titles of now-deleted questions for users without the privilege to view most deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158906/review-history-appears-not-to-escape-html-tags-in-titles-of-now-deleted-question)

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me:

[image]

Comment: Hrm, may be a browser-specific issue.

Comment: I'll take a look.  Which browser were you using?